# What is a smart and/or pythonic approach to writing functions with constraints on function arguments?

Tags: python, design-patterns, types, constraints

Suppose I wanted to write a Python function in which the arguments to this function should only ever be used with e.g. lists of equal length.

Let's imagine a python-like pseudocode implementation which might look like:

```py
 def somefunc(arg1: list, arg2: list) -> list, where len(arg1) == len(arg2):
```

What is the pythonic approach to writing a function, where passing arguments which do not satisfy such constraints would result in a (run-time) error.

Comment: Just throw an `if len(arg1) != len(arg2):` in there (at the beginning of your function) and raise a `ValueError`, which, according to the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError), is "raised when an operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value".

Comment: @Carcigenicate, you're absolutely right, thank you!

Comment: Generally you can use the type system to your advantage.  In this case, instead of expecting two lists, you could expect a list of two-tuples (this can be produced with zip(list1, list2).

Comment: Note that unless a misuse is very, very common, it is usually unpythonic to check it. There is a myriad of ways to misuse a function, and in all but the most primitive case they are prohibitively expensive to check exhaustively.

Comment: What you are looking for is support for dependent types, where you can include a size in the type. In pseudocode, it might look like `def somefunc(arg1: list[size=n], arg2: list[size=n]):`. Having `n` as the size in both types could be used to ensure that the list have the same size. However, `mypy` doesn't support dependent types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per discussions in the comments, such function parameter and type and value constraints can be achieved in python at run-time by raising a ValueError.

```py
def somefunc(arg1: list, arg2: list) -> list:
    if (len(arg1) != len(arg2)):
        raise ValueError
```